# How can I extract a part of this url with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an url that looks like this:

http://localhost/assets/upload/img/hw6dNDBT-36x36.jpg

I want to extract `hw6dNDBT.jpg`, from the url above.

I tried playing around with regex patterns `/img\/.*-/` but that
matches with `img/hw6dNDBT-`.

How can I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: Can you show your code as well?  You're close (you just need a capturing group), but seeing your existing code will enable us to answer more specifically.

Comment: you need to make your regex non selecting on the img part but still matching. I know its possible though can't remember how. aside from that, you can also use a split function with an index of function to find 'img/' and pull everything after that.

Comment: Will the path always end in `.jpg` and/or will it always contain the `-36x36`?  Will those numbers vary in length?

Comment: I'm curious as to what your actual problem is. What I mean is why do you need to get the name of the image? Where is the image in relation to the javascript? is it on a webpage? I believe that would be possible using JS and html elements on the page assuming there is one which would make your life alot easier

Comment: @RichardBarker Using HTML elements and interacting with the DOM is probably far slower than using a (actually fairly simple) regex.

Comment: @JamesThorpe OP never mentioned anything about performance. With that in mind would you rather have more complicated code or less time to execute?

Comment: @RichardBarker Personally I think using elements would be far more complicated.  Regex is a simple, straightforward solution here.

Comment: @JamesThorpe LOL Regex is simple?

Comment: @RichardBarker Not always, but in this case, yes, and is also the approach the OP seems to want to take.  It's designed for pattern matching strings, which is precisely what the OP wants to do.  It's exactly the right tool for the job.  The one in jcubic's answer really isn't doing anything complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```js
var url = 'http://localhost/assets/upload/img/hw6dNDBT-36x36.jpg';
var filename = url.match(/img\/(.*)-[^.]+(\.[^.]+)/).slice(1).join('');
document.body.innerHTML = filename;
```

Answer (score 0):

i would use split() method:

```
var str = "http://localhost/assets/upload/img/hw6dNDBT-36x36.jpg";
var strArr = str.split("/");
var size = strArr.length - 1;
var needle = strArr[size].split("-");
var fileTypeArr = strArr[size].split(".");
var name = needle[0]+"."+fileTypeArr[fileTypeArr.length-1];
```

`name` should now be your searched String so far it contains no `/` inside it

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 0):

`/[^\/]+$/` should match all characters after the last `/` in the URL, which seems to be what you want to match.

Answer (score 0):

No regex:

```
//this is a hack that lets the anchor tag do some parsing for you
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = 'http://localhost/assets/upload/img/hw6dNDBT-36x36.jpg';

//optional if you know you can always trim the start of the path
var path = parser.pathname.replace('/assets/uploads/');
var parts = path.split('/');
var img = '';

for(var i=0; i<parts.length; i++) {
    if (parts[i] == 'img') {
        //since we know the .jpg always follows 'img/'
        img = parts[i+1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, you were so close! You just need to take your regex and use a **capturing group**, and then add a littttle bit more!

```
img\/(.*)-.*(\..*)
```

So, you can use that in this manner:

```
var result = /img\/(.*)-.*(\..*)/.exec();
var filename = result[1] + result[2];
```

Honestly capturing the `.jpg`, is a little excessive, if you know they are all going to be JPG images, you can probably just take out the second half of the regex.

Incase you are wondering, why do we uses `result[1]` and `result[2]`? Because `result[0]` stores the *entire* match, which is what you were getting back. The captured groups, which is what we create when we use the parentheses, are stored as the indexes after 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some one-liner:

```
var myUrl = 'http://localhost/assets/upload/img/hw6dNDBT-36x36.jpg',
    myValue = myUrl.split('/').pop().replace(/-(?=\d).[^.]+/,'');
```

We take everything after the last slash then cut out the dimension part.